# Using Django SessionStore in Celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-sessions

I'm really struggling with something and have tried for days to find out what I'm doing wrong..I was thinking there might be something fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to do but I cant find anything to suggest that.

I am trying to use Celery to modify a Django Session DB in the background.

As a test, I have a test view which passes the sessionid to this celery task:

```
@shared_task(name="test_celery_task")
def test_celery_task(sessionid):
    s = SessionStore(session_key='sessionid')
    s['test_var'] = ["Success"]
    s.save()
    return "Task Complete"
```

I can see the task runs, and I have added a few loggers in to check the session ID gets passed, and no error are thrown up etc.

When I do this in the manage.py shell, it works fine. But I guess this is not working because it is being run by a celery worker.

If it is not possible, then so be it and I'll save my time trying to work out what's wrong, but all I have read suggests that I should be able to manipulate models etc within Celery without an issue, and that a session is just another model.

Am I going about this all wrong? Does anyone have any experience with Django SessionStore and Celery. Thanks!

Comment: Is the line in your code actually `s = SessionStore(session_key='sessionid')`? You are using the string "sessionid" and not the passed parameter if so

Comment: I've just logged back in to update this that after days I had just realised this myself - but thank you so much for pointing it out too. I can't believe it was such a basic error. Unfortunately it didn't throw up any exceptions so had just been sitting there causing mischief. I guess when I had been testing in the shell I had been replacing sessionid with the actual string, which obviously works.  Silly mistake but I'll leave this here in case anyone else searches for Celery, Django and SessionStore as much as I have the last couple of days!